# How to leave a docker container ran without -i?

Tags: docker

I ran my container with:

```
docker run --name dev-env --tty --rm sauloefo/my-ubuntu-lunar /bin/bash
```

As you can see, I forgot the `-i` option so now any command I type I don't get the output.
From the docs, my understanding is that my computer is still attached to the STDIN but the container is attached to the STDOUT/STDERR so whatever I type I don't get the output.

Can somebody tell me if my understanding is correct?

But my real pain is to leave the container: how can i do that?

Comment: You should be able to detach from the container by pressing Ctrl-P, Ctrl-Q. It only works sometimes for me though and I haven't figured out why it only works sometimes. Another way is to open a new terminal and kill the container using `docker kill dev-env`.

Comment: it might work as long as you're not running from VS Code terminal! In this case, it closes VS Code.